# How can I use Webdriver (Selenium2) locator By.id to locate PrimeFaces autogenerated ID's with Colons ":" appended

Tags: primefaces, webdriver

When trying to send text to a TextBox created via PrimeFaces:

I try:

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id("addRowTable:0:hostName")).sendKeys("testing");
```

Html is:

Enter Hostname:$(function() {PrimeFaces.cw('Watermark','widget_addRowTable_0_j_idt474',{id:'addRowTable:0:j_idt474',value:'Hostname',target:'addRowTable:0:hostName'},'watermark');});
                    PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_addRowTable_0_hostName',{id:'addRowTable:0:hostName'});.xxxxcxxxxxdddddddddd.net

I get the XPath as:

```
//*[@id="addRowTable:0:hostName"]
```

I get exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"addRowTable\\:0\\:hostName"}
Command duration or timeout: 149 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

When i look at

```
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

i get a generic explanation:

```
The element may not be present.
```

Even Escaping : with \ did not work

```
getDriver().findElement(By.id("addRowTable\\:0\\:hostName")).sendKeys("testing");
```

Answer (score 0):

In our applications we never directly check for the full ID because it is dependent on the position of the component in the JSF component tree.

Rather what you should use is the CSS **ends with** ($=) operator.

```java
getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id$=\"hostName\"]")).sendKeys("testing");
```

Or, using [page objects](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects):

```java
public class MyPage extends PageObject {

    @FindBy(css="input[id$=\"hostName\"]")
    private WebElement hostName;

    public void setHostName(String hostName) {
        hostName.sendKeys("testing");
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but 
I am getting Exception: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Any idea how this is resolved

Comment: Did you retrieve an object of the `MyPage` page object like this: `PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), MyPage.class)`? Otherwise the `hostName` field will not be linked to the actual element in the browser.